# Alternate between titles and paragraphs with itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I'm trying to write a pdf document with itextsharp but I wont to alternate between two styles: the title and the paragraph.

I tryed something like this:

```
Paragraph title= new Paragraph();
title.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
title.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 32);
title.Add("\nTitle 1\n\n");
pdfDoc.Add(title);


Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
paragraph.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12);
paragraph.Add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \n");
pdfDoc.Add(paragraph);


title.Add("\nTitle 2\n\n");
pdfDoc.Add(title);
paragraph.Add("Consectetur adipiscing elit \n");
pdfDoc.Add(paragraph);
```

But it looks like I need to clear the content before adding the new text. Is it possible to clear just the text or would I have to create new variables for each paracgraph? Hope not....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to fix your problem is to change your code like this:

```
Font titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 32);
Font regularFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 36);
Paragraph title;
Paragraph text;
title = new Paragraph("Title", titleFont);
title.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
pdfDoc.Add(title);
text = new Paragraph("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", regularFont);
pdfDoc.Add(text);
title = new Paragraph("Title 2", titleFont);
title.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
pdfDoc.Add(title);
text = new Paragraph("Consectetur adipiscing elit", regularFont);
pdfDoc.Add(text);
```

It would be considered a serious bug if content would disappear after adding text. It would mean that objects that are used once, can no longer be reused. In short: in your question, you are asking the developers of iTextSharp to introduce a bug...

Typically, one creates a separate class defining all the `Font` objects that are used. It is also a good idea to create a helper class with custom methods such as `getTitle()`, `getText()`, etc, similar to the [PojoToElementFactory](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Intro_1_2/PojoToElementFactory.cs) class (note that POJO stands for Plain Old Java Object. The original code was written in Java, by... yours truly).

It is a **bad** idea to use `\n` to introduce newlines. Why aren't you using properties such as the *leading*, the *spacing before* and the *spacing after* to define white space between the lines?

Comment: It works just as I want, thank you! I use \n because I'm still learning and I don't know anyting, but I'll try to replace it with the spacing before/after, it seems much cleaner.